# MongoDB: sort by relevance function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I want to create a basic sorting algorithm determined by relevance in mongodb and meteor. However, I cannot store this statically and update it because it uses current time as one of the parameters.

Ideally, what I'd like to have is something like as follows:

```
Post.relevance = function(magnitude) {
  magnitude = magnitude || 1.8;
  check(magnitude, Number);
  var score = this.upvotes - this.downvotes;
  var hoursAgo = moment().hours - moment(this.createdAt).hours();
  return (score - 1) / Math.pow((hoursAgo + 2), magnitude);
}
```

From what I gather, I will have to use the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to generate this query, but I can't quite get the details for my post page.

How would one generate this advanced query using mongodb?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to generate a relevance attribute for each of your Posts and then sort and filter the information by relevance (quantitative)? Also, what is the schema of your db?

Comment: yeah, I want people to go to the homepage and see the most relevant posts first, sorted by that function. The schema of the db currently only have posts, users, and comments. Posts contain `title`, `link`, `authorId`, `createdAt`, `editedAt`, `upvotes`, and `downvotes`

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm depends on how you define relevance.

Before going on, I'd like to mention that I haven't previously implemented such an algorithm in a production environment and I am only expressing my personal opinion on how I would tackle this.

Personally, according to your schema, I would consider the following methods to be the most common in determining relevance:

- Relevance in terms of popularity - this is how search engines
  determine the relevance of content: the more views a website, the
  more relevant it is
- Relevance in terms of quality - in your case, you could go for a dynamic generated algorithm in terms of upvotes/downvotes ratio
- Time relevance - the way you are currently quantifying the relevance, using an algorithm that uses time as a filtering mechanism; still, I wouldn't go with this one as relevant content will always be valuable

Out of the 3 aforementioned scenarios, I would recommend you go for a mix between the first two.

You have to find a good way to represent the relationship between view popularity, upvotes and downvotes. This means that you first have to update your database schema in order for it to hold a view count for each post:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    title: 'A Random Post',
    authorId: ObjectId(...),
    createdAt: '01-01-1900',
    editedAt: '02-01-1900',
    upvotes: 76,
    downvotes: 15,
    viewCount: 8655,
    relevance:

}
```

Afterwards, you can determine a formula to calculate the relevance. For example, if you assume that the more views a post gets, the more popular it is, you could use the following formula:

```
Relevance = viewCount * upvotes/downvotes
```

Still, the most important part is how you choose to store the relevance attribute.

As I see it, you have two possible options:

- Store it in the database alongside all the other elements - this
  means that you would have to constantly update the relevance for each
  post, while continuously issuing `$inc` updates for viewCount,
  upvotes and downvotes
- Determine the relevance after querying the database- only issue
  `$inc` updates for viewCount, upvotes and downvotes; after pulling
  the data from the database, you would have to parse the resulting
  array and quantify the relevance, without storing it in the database

Obviously, the first scenario would generate a lot more strain on the server due to a greater number of update operations. Still, it would allow you to query relevant posts by firing a simple query.

```
//Top 10 most relevant posts
db.posts.find({}).sort({ relevance: -1 }).limit(10);
```

If you go with the second option, you would first have to pull all the documents from the database and then do some extra work to determine the relevance, before sending the data from the server.